# General way to solve equations of congruent classes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, congruences

So I'm taking my first abstract algebra class, and I have some homework like "Solve the equation $x^2 + [3]\times x+[2]=[0]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$. This doesn't seem to difficult to do since I can easily plug in all the congruent classes in $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

But then I have this one: Solve $x^3 + x^2 = [2]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, and apparently it's a little bit tedious to go through all classes, but still doable.

But what if I need to solve it in $\mathbb{Z}_{7832}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{2367283952}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an amazing trick called the Chinese Remainder Theorem.
It lets you rewrite $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ as $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ as long as $m, n$ are coprime.

If $m, n$ are coprime, you can find integers $a,b$ such that $am+bn = 1$.

The mappings are $[k] \mapsto ([k],[k])$ and $([k],[l]) \mapsto [bk + al]$

Now you can solve a problem in $\mathbb{F}_{10}$ by solving it in $\mathbb{F}_5$ and $\mathbb{F}_2$, and then combining the solutions back to something in $\mathbb{F}_{10}$.

Assuming conversion is trivial, the speedup is obvious. You only have to evaluate your polynomial $m+n$ times, instead of $mn$ times.

Unfortunately, this doesn't help with large primes/large prime powers

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: A trick for large prime powers is Hensel lifting.